# Possible telescopic sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, trigonometric-series, telescopic-series

> Prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n 4^{k}\sin^{4} \left(\frac{a}{2^k}\right) =  4^{n}\sin^{2} \left(\frac{a}{2^n}\right) - \sin^{2}a$$

---

I suspect that telescopic sum is involved but don't know how to proceed. Please do not use induction, since the problem was given as objective.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: $2^{2k}=4^k$, then try induction.

Comment: @GarethMa  without induction please.

Comment: @Shashank how would you expect to solve it then? Induction is the most natural thing to do here. I guess it might be possible to somehow expand and telescope. Do you not know induction or something?

Comment: @GarethMa I know induction but I dont want to do it that way. This question came in objective type question in my exam. I want it to somehow expand and use telescopic sum

Comment: @DavidK it came in objective type questions

Comment: @DavidK Also if the meaning of 'multiple choice questions' is not clear to you, then it means in an exam you have more than one options given to you ,for answers, for a problem out of which one or more options may be correct. Ah, yes I have the answers now. Thank you.

Comment: I'm perfectly well familiar with multiple choice question, though I don't think I've ever seen one that asked to prove anything. At least next time you might think of using more well-known terminology. I also might have been more inclined to post my answer rather than a critique if it didn't sound so much like you were in the middle of an exam. Possibly just a wrong impression. I think you know how to ask a question better than this, so maybe just leave it at that.

Comment: @DavidK there was this summation on LHS given in the question and the 4 options had different results and the correct answer was to be ticked and the correct answer was the one that I have wrote on RHS here and no solution was provided so i asked it in this format here.

Comment: That would have been a fine question if presented according to the last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render

$4^k\sin^4(\dfrac{a}{2^k})=4^k\sin^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})\color{blue}{\sin^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})}=4^k\sin^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})-4^k\sin^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})\cos^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})$

And then, with the double angle formula $\sin 2x= 2\sin x\cos x$:

$\sin^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})\cos^2(\dfrac{a}{2^k})=(4^{-1})\sin^2(\dfrac{a}{2^{k-1}})$

Substitute the right side of the second equation for the sine-cosine product in the first one and identify the telescoping difference.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin^4 x= \sin^2 x(1-\cos^2 )= \sin^2 x- 4^{-1} \sin^2 2x$$
Let $x=a/2^n$ then we get the right differencing as

$$4^n\sin^4\frac{ a}{2^n}= \left(4^n \sin^2 \frac{a}{2^n}- 4^{n-1} \sin^2 \frac{a}{2^{n-1}} \right),$$ For telescopic summation.